# `kill -s TERM` works, `kill -s ABRT` gets "Operation not permitted"

Tags: permissions, freebsd, kill, signals, ruby

There is a process that I own whose documentation claims I can send `SIGABRT` to in order to get some debugging information. However, when I try to send `SIGABRT`, I get back "Operation not permitted".

I have also tried sending the same signals to other processes I own to make sure that there isn't some underlying block preventing me from sending `SIGABRT` altogether, but they respond in the appropriate manner.  It's just this one program, but it's every instance of that program.  A system call trace of the process shows that it never receives the signal.

I have tried running `/bin/kill` explicitly in order to rule out any weirdness in my shell's builtin `kill`, and, other than some minor output differences, there was no change in behavior.

root can send `SIGABRT` to the process and it works as I expect it to.

I've been in this game for a while, but I've never seen an instance where a user is not able to send a signal to a process that he owns, nor have I seen an instance where a user can send one signal but not another.

The OS is FreeBSD 9.0 and the process is a ruby process that is part of a Phusion Passenger Ruby-on-Rails application running under Apache.

I'm currently at a total loss.  Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

*Update:* Turns out that the `security.bsd.conservative_signals` sysctl was set to 1, and that prevents many signals from being delivered to setuid processes, according to the man page.  Setting it to 0 solves the problem.

While there was a setuid call somewhere up the process chain — the process is a child of an Apache httpd, and Apache changes its uid to relinquish root permissions — the process itself is not setuid, and its EUID, RUID, and SVUID are all the same as the user sending the signal.  The only inspection of the process that I can find that would indicate that any setuid happened is the `P_SUGID` flag in `ps`'s "flags" field.  ("Had set id privileges since last exec")  It seems like that shouldn't be the case, but it's handled in an Apache module and I don't know its exact methods.

For the record, it's a ruby process that's functioning as part of a Ruby on Rails application being handled by mod_passenger, AKA mod_rails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [latest version of the kill(2) manpage](http://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/lib/libc/sys/kill.2?revision=241855&view=co):

> For a process to have permission to send a signal to a process designated
>   by
>   pid,
>   the user must be the super-user, or
>   the real or saved user ID of the receiving process must match
>   the real or effective user ID of the sending process.
>   A single exception is the signal SIGCONT, which may always be sent
>   to any process with the same session ID as the sender.
>   In addition, **if the
>   security.bsd.conservative_signals
>   sysctl
>   is set to 1, the user is not a super-user, and
>   the receiver is set-uid**, then
>   only job control and terminal control signals may
>   be sent (in particular, only SIGKILL, SIGINT, SIGTERM, SIGALRM,
>   SIGSTOP, SIGTTIN, SIGTTOU, SIGTSTP, SIGHUP, SIGUSR1, SIGUSR2).

In what sense do you own the process? What exactly is the status of the process relating to real uid, effective uid, what binary it is running, owner and setid-bits of that binary, etc?

Comment: `security.bsd.conservative_signals` is definitely the culprit, but the environment doesn't seem to match the description in the man page.  I'll edit the question to add this info.